# React Router 6 - pass data/state from action to loader with different route path

Tags: react-router, parameter-passing, action, toast, loader

I have an app with list of posts and post's detail. Now I am trying to figure out how to effectively show toast with some text after post is editted.

Let's say that I have:

```
import { Form } from "react-router-dom"

<PostDetail>
    const navigation = useNavigation()

    const isSubmitting = navigation.formData?.get("title") != null

    <Form>
        <input type="text" name="title" />
        <button>
            {isSubmitting ? "Saving..." : "Save"}
        </button>
    </Form>
</PostDetail>
```

After form submit do some stuff on Action function (https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/action) and then redirect to the page with list of posts.

```
const postAction = async ({ request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) => {
    const formData = await request.formData()

    // call BE to update post and do some other stuff

    return redirect("/post/list")
}
```

After that I want to **show some toast alert on the page with list of posts** f.e. *(Hey, your post has been updated...)*

Am I able to send some info/status from action `/post/:id` to loader `post/list`?

Answer (score 0):

I played with some solutions.

**1)** In `postAction()` do not return a `redirect()`, but some data (`{status: "post-updated"}`). Then in  use `useActionData()` hook to get the status, show toast and the redirect force from a component via `navigate('/post/list')`

```
<PostDetail>
    const actionData = useActionData()
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const navigation = useNavigation()

    const isSubmitting = navigation.formData?.get("title") != null

    if (actionData?.status === "post-updated") {
       // show toast message
       navigate('/post/list')
    }

    ....
</PostDetail>
```

This solution wasn't good for me, because I am also using `useNavigation()` hook to check "isSubmitting" state and display different text in my submit button. When the action function returned success status, `useNavigation()` returned `state: "idle"`, not `state: "submitting"`. So there was a little glitch (blink) in text, before the redirect was forced.

**2)** Second solution for me is add a search param directly into action function. And the toast message force in the  component, where I check the search params. This is working but I don't like the messy code around. Like useEffect add useRef to prevent rendering etc.

```
const postAction = async ({ request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) => {
    ....
    return redirect("/post/list?alert=edit")
}
```

```
const PostList = () => {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams()

  const render = React.useRef(true)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (render.current) {
      render.current = false
      if (searchParams.has("alert")) {
        // show toast with message...
        searchParams.delete("alert")
        setSearchParams(searchParams, { replace: true })
      }
    }
  }, [])

}
```

So my question is. Is there any other solution, how to pass some data between action and loader?

Thanks!